# filtering using antD in React JavaScript

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a table which requires filtering. I am writing as a component class and not a function. When I try to filter the column, it gives me an error saying

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes') - using this for filtering on a text..

Idea values are "Choc Flavor" and "Mini Packs" so am trying to create basic filter but when I select the filter, it filters all values and shows me nothing.

```
render() {

    const onChange = (pagination, filters, sorter, extra) => {
      console.log('params', pagination, filters, sorter, extra);
    };

    const columns = [
      {
        title: 'Stack Rank',
        key: 'stackRank',
        dataIndex: 'rank',
        sorter: (a, b) => a.rank - b.rank,
      },
      {
        title: 'Idea',
        dataIndex: 'title',
        key: 'idea',
        sorter: (a, b) => a.title.length - b.title.length,
{
        text: 'Mini',
        value: 'Mini',
      },
      {
        text: 'Choc Flavor',
        value: 'Choc Flavor',
      },
    ],
    onFilter: (value, record) => record.title?.includes(value) === 0,            render: (_, record) => (
          <Space size="middle">
            <Link to={'/idea-detail/'+ this.product_id+'/'+record.ideaId} >{record.title}</Link>
          </Space>
        ),
      },
       {
        title: 'Votes',
        dataIndex: 'voteCount',
        key: 'voteCount',
        sorter: (a, b) => a.voteCount - b.voteCount,
        onFilter: (value, record) => record.voteCount.includes(value),
        sortDirections: ['descend', 'ascend'],

       },    
    ];



    return (
<Table columns={columns} dataSource={this.state.idea_list} onChange={onChange}   pagination={{
    }} />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the fact that one or all of the item in the array variable `this.state.idea_list` do not contain the 'idea' field or it is undefined.

A solution would be to change `onFilter` function like this:

```
onFilter: (value, record) => record.idea?.includes(value) === 0
```

Comment: I do have the array as I can see the values populate in the table. I replaced the line of code so it didnt give me any error but when I filter, it filters out everything.

Comment: the field was "title" but it still not working. There is no error but when I filter it just hides all values